# How can I shortcut a test for unique values in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'd like to check if a column in a Spark Dataframe has only unique values. I could use `df.groupby("key").count().agg({"count":"max"})`, but this will always treat the whole table.

I'd like that Spark finishes early if it finds any duplicate value (ideally even telling me this value). The idea is to use mechanisms like `.take(1)` which can shortcut (unless all values are unique)?!

Is there any way I can achieve that in Pyspark?

Comment: First of all, when doing an aggregation, keys need to be moved to same executors (shuffle). This is the most expensive part of counting duplicates. Whatever logic you choose, you will need to move keys to the same executor (i.e. shuffle) to then be able to count them. I can't see a way of avoiding the shuffle. Whatever goes after the shuffle, is not worth manual optimization IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a shortcut to achieve your goal.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use the iterative / recursive "concept" to check your duplication in your dataframe. Once you find the duplicated row, you won't check the next row and somehow "break" your logic check and return the result to you.

As Spark is a distributed computing engine, once you use the spark api / your own UDF, it will apply to all records but not the chosen record. You can definitely use some sampling / mathematical method to reduce your dataframe size and do the approximation calculation, but it still apply to your sampled dataset.

To conclude, I don't think there is a shortcut to achieve your goal. If you find the solution, please let me how to do that as I'm interested in it too.

Comment: `.take(1)` somehow shortcuts the execution? Shouldn't there be some way to make Spark output a row after the first value duplication? I mean logically that's certainly possible. Spark should output a row after a duplicated value and not bother trying more values.

Comment: @Gerenuk When you say `.take(1)`, it's no doubt that `.first()` or `take(1)` is one of the cheapest actions and it just pull `1` record back to the driver, but what kind of record / infomration do you want to take to achieve your goal?

Comment: Return one arbitrary duplicated value quickly (if there is one)